# Hair on the legs, hair on the hands

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for hair on the legs or hands?

Can we say *legs hair* or *hands hair*, or do we use another word?

Comment: There's no term for hair **on any part** including head/scalp. You have to make it a two-word-noun phrase. Scalp hair, leg hair, arm hair, facial hair and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a noun adjunct: leg hair / arm hair

or use a possessive: leg's hair / arm's hair (ie. the hair belonging to arm/leg, stressing the leg/arm as owners)

Comment: "Leg hair" and "arm hair" are correct, but the possessive doesn't sit right with me. I don't think anyone would ever say that.

Comment: I shaved off my left leg's hair.  I singed most of my right arm's hair.  Why not?

Comment: Even in such context, while the possessives seem more appropriate, the more common way I would hear such sentences phrased would be "I shaved my left leg", "I shaved the hair off my left leg", "I singed most of the hair on my right arm" (NE US).

Answer (score 0):

You may  say: **hairy hands** and **hairy legs** to refer to the hair that  cover hands and legs.

Comment: Wouldn't actually refer to the **hands** and **legs** that are covered in hair? I mean, a hairy face refers to the **face**, whereas a beard refers to the **hair**. One implies the other, of course :)

Comment: It refers to the hair that you naturally have on your body.

Comment: Sorry, but _hairy_ is an adjective, modifying the _noun_ hands. So you are talking about the hands, saying they are hairy, not about the hair, saying it's on the hand. By the way, what would be hair you do _not_ have naturally on your body, short from implants and costumes stuff?

Comment: I am just giving my answer to OP. I thinks OP is asking a way to describe hands and legs covered with hair.

Comment: Possibly. But then I would advise the asker to rephrase the question, because the question is now about the hair, not about the arms and legs. You may well be right in interpreting the question like this, I don;t know. My only point was that the question as it stands looks for a word for "hair covering the face" => _beard_ and you answer with _hairy face_. But indeed, yuo may have read the OP's mind better than I did :)

Comment: You are right, questions are not always clear. But different interpretations, I think, makes this site more lively.  :)

Comment: No argument there :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14375/discussion-between-josh61-and-oerkelens)

Answer (score -1):

Hirsute. Conveys general hairiness so you'd have to include other body parts